# How can i get the status of product in magento cart by customer id and product id?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I want to get the status of customer cart for a particular products that is products added in his cart or removed. I have loop of products and each products have customer and i have customer_id , product_id now i want to check that is this products added in customer cart or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ad the following method to needed class:

```
public function getProductInCart($customer, $productId, $storeId = null)
{
    if (!$customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer);
    }

    if (!$customer->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($storeId === null) {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getWebsite(true)->getDefaultGroup()->getDefaultStoreId();
    }
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customer);

    if (!$quote->getId()) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        if($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Using example:

```
$this->getProductsInCart(customer_id, product_id, store_id)
```

Comment: Not working for me i have create a custom module for admin section to verify the products that customer reserve before checkout and i will approve that i try user function and i dont have any storeId and default is is showing 1 so can you please let me know in which table the cart is saved  Then i can check directory from that tables using custom query based on productId and customerId